# Difference between append("svg:g") and append("g")

Tags: syntax, svg, append

I work on a d3js project and I saw some tutorial with `append("g")` and other with `append("svg:g")` without getting the difference between both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the very early days of D3 you were required to use the `svg:g` syntax because of the way SVG elements are appended to the DOM. Later versions of D3 don't require these "hints" to insert SVG elements, so the proper way to do this now would be with a simple `g`.

---

The technical details behind this are rather dull, SVG requires a namespace, so when you insert or manipulate SVG elements you use `document.createElementNS('a', "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg)` white plain HTML uses `document.createElement('a')`. Since D3 can manipulate both SVG and HTML `d3.append('svg:a')` was a way of saying *this is an SVG anchor.*

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer on d3js API, its a namespace question. In svg:g, svg is the namespace (optional).
My fault, sorry i must better read API